# hide input type="range" slider-thumb in webkit

Tags: html, css, firefox, webkit

until safari 5.1 and maybe 6.0 it was possible to hide the slider-thumb via css

```
input[type=range].onoff::-webkit-slider-thumb,
input[type=range].onoff::-moz-slider-thumb,
input[type=range].onoff::slider-thumb {  
    -webkit-appearance: none !important;
    -moz-appearance: none !important;
    appearance: none !important;
    height:20px; width:20px;
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

worked also in chrome, ff and opera.

now with safari 6.1 and 6.1.1, firefox 25
this css is not hiding the slider-thumb anymore.
what did i miss?
is there a better, more valid code i could use to hide just the thumb?

no jquery solutions please, i work on a native javascript plugin to add touchable audio-wheels, working in different environments. maybe later i will translate this to jQ too.

Answer (score 0):

okay testet..

looks like, the comma separated list of selectors and setting them all ot once is not working anymore. so valid code can be..

```
input[type=range].onoff::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
input[type=range].onoff::-moz-slider-thumb {
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
input[type=range].onoff::slider-thumb {
    appearance: none;
}
```

but still in FF i can't hide the thumb, how?

Comment: Firefox uses "range" not "slider". so if you want to style the thumb in Firefox use: `::moz-range-thumb`

Comment: Has IE10-11 own version of slider-thumb or range-thumb?